# Location Listener works in Android 6.0 but not android 8.0+

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation

I'm learning about using geolocation in apps and I have this issue where I can get the location of a user when emulating Android 6.0 but when I try to run the same exact code in Android 8.0, I don't get the location of the user. I honestly don't understand where I'm wrong or why it isn't working. Here is my code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
                Log.i("Location", location.toString());
            }
        };

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            //Ask for permission

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by adding this else statement after I check the permission of the fine location.

**Code Below:**

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
 
    //Ask for permission
 
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
 
}else {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
```

**Reason:**

It seems that locationUpdate only works on the first try of my app because I only set my locationUpdate in the onRequestPermissionResult code block. My onRequesPermissionResult only runs when I request permission and by the next time I run the app, I already have permission from my user, So in the code, I'm checking for permission, which will return false because I already have permission granted and I didn't set locationUpdate if Permission is already granted.

So I tried adding the else statement above.

**Simplified Problem:**

- first time I open the app, my app didn't have permission to the location(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), yet.
- My permission checking line will return true and you request the permission.
- onRequestPermissionResult will run and you write code to set locationUpdate in it and it worked.

-The next time that I opened the app, my app already had permission to the location.

- My permission checking line will return false and it's not going to execute the code inside the scope, so no request permission was executed.
- My location didn't have locationUpdate because the onReuqestionPermissionResult method didn't execute.

**Solution:**

- I set the condition if the check permission returned false, that means the permission was already granted, so I don't have to request permission but just set locationUpdate for your locationManager.